# An assignment generates a System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, .net, clr

```
IObjectVmFactory objectVMFactory = this.Container.Resolve<IObjectVmFactory>();
```

This throws a NullReferenceException.

If I do not assign the result of `this.Container.Resolve` to a variable, it does not throw:

```
this.Container.Resolve<IObjectVmFactory>().AnyMethod(...)
```

This has no sense to me ... someone can give me some explanation?

**Extra information:**

`this.Container` is not null for sure. Triple checked. And if it was null the second line would fail.

The class implementing `IObjectVmFactory` has no defined constructor so the exception is not happening inside the `IObjectVmFactory` implementation.

The exception has no inner exceptions and points directly to the first line.

Executing the line directly on the Inmediate Window generates a ('' is null) message.

Thanks!

Comment: First one is `this.Container.Resolve<IObjectVmFactory>();` while second one is `this.Container.Resolve<IObjectVmFactory>().CreateInstance(...)`. Your code itself explains that first one is not creating an instance of it while the second one is. Hence it is self explanatory.

Comment: Are you sure that `Container` isn't `null`? Where does the `NullReferenceException` come from?

Comment: First one is creating an instance of IObjectVmFactory, te second also.The only difference is that in the first case I assign the instance resolved by unity in a variable. Container is ok, not null.

Comment: Edited the question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

My project's configuration was in Release, not Debug. In release mode, it throws an exception at the assignment. In debug, it throws on the step AFTER the assignment:

```
Foo member { get; }
public Bar(Foo foo)
{
    // crashes here on release
    member = foo; 

    // crashes here in debug (foo.Collection was null)
    foreach (var thing in foo.Collection) 
        thing.DoSomething();
}
```

So it looks like having the project's configuration in release may cause the error. Try switching the configuration to debug and find where it's failing.

Go to Build -> Configuration Manager

Select your project

Change the configuration from Release to Debug.

Build and see if the error occurs at the same place.